# How to prepend an element to a list in Mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

Mongoengine can push elements to Lists by appending them

```
BlogPost.objects(id=post.id).update_one(push__tags='nosql')
```

I want to prepend instead of appending, is there a way ?

Another alternate question to the same problem ..
I can query in a list by position like this

```
BlogPost.objects(tags__0='nosql')
```

Is there a way to specify the last element in the list, like -1 index in python lists ?

```
BlogPost.objects(tags__-1='nosql')# ?.. I wish !
```

Answers to any of two question will solve my problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also asked at http://groups.google.com/group/mongoengine-users/browse_thread/thread/ab05888b36d1465e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of those operations is possible, but you can work around it fairly easily by emulating access to the last array element with another field. Suppose your model is:

```
class BlogPost(Document):
    tags = ListField(StringField())
    # other things
```

Add a field `last_tag`:

```
class BlogPost(Document):
    tags = ListField(StringField())
    last_tag = StringField()
    # other things
```

Then, when updating:

```
BlogPost.objects(id=post.id).update_one(push__tags='nosql', set__last_tag='nosql')
```

And when querying:

```
BlogPost.objects(last_tag='nosql')
```

You'll want to make sure that `last_tag` is indexed, and possibly also `tags` if you query by that frequently as well.

Comment: the problem with this approach is that I have to duplicate the last list items, as the item is not a simple string, it is a huge embedded document.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I was able to achieve a proper prepend was to use the pythonic way of prepending to a list and then saving the document. Like so:

```
blog_post = BlogPost.objects.get(id=post.id)
blog_post.tags.insert(0,'nosql')
blog_post.save()
```

Unfortunately MongoEngine for Python has not yet provided a proper way to use the $position operator for $push.